# Print inside MapReduce class

Tags: java, hadoop

I have this example of MapReduce [1], and I want to print info in the stdout and in a log file[3]. It seems that the logs isn’t print something. How can I make my `map` class print output?

I also have configured `yarn-site.xml` to retain log[2]. Although the logs are retained in the `/app-logs dir`, the `userlogs` dir that contains the output of the job execution is deleted at the end of the job execution. How can I make MapReduce to not delete files in the `userlogs` dir?

I am using Yarn.

Thanks,

[1] Wordcount exampla with just the map part.

```
public class MyWordCount {
  public static class MyMap extends Mapper {
    Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyWordCount.class);
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        System.out.println("HERRE");
        log.info("HERRRRRE");
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(itr.nextToken());
            output.collect(word, one);
        }
    }

    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        setup(context);
        try {
            while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
                System.out.println("Key: " + context.getCurrentKey() + " Value: " + context.getCurrentValue());
                map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
            }
        } finally {
            cleanup(context);
        }
    }

    public void cleanup(Mapper.Context context) {}
}
```

[2] yarn-site.xml

```
    <!-- job history -->
    <property> <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name> <value>true</value> </property>
    <property> <name>yarn.nodemanager.log.retain-seconds</name> <value>900000</value> </property>
    <property> <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name> <value>/app-logs</value> </property>
```

​[3] log output

```
Log Type: stderr
Log Upload Time: 24-Sep-2015 12:45:19
Log Length: 317
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: You have loaded library /home/xubuntu/Programs/hadoop-2.6.0/lib/native/libhadoop.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Log Type: stdout
Log Upload Time: 24-Sep-2015 12:45:19
Log Length: 0
Log Type: syslog
Log Upload Time: 24-Sep-2015 12:45:19
Log Length: 2604
2015-09-24 12:45:04,569 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2015-09-24 12:45:05,139 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2015-09-24 12:45:05,412 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2015-09-24 12:45:05,413 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics system started
2015-09-24 12:45:05,462 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Executing with tokens:
2015-09-24 12:45:05,463 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Kind: mapreduce.job, Service: job_1443113036547_0001, Ident: (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.token.JobTokenIdentifier@1b5a082)
2015-09-24 12:45:05,847 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Sleeping for 0ms before retrying again. Got null now.
2015-09-24 12:45:06,915 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: mapreduce.cluster.local.dir for child: /tmp/hadoop-temp/nm-local-dir/usercache/xubuntu/appcache/application_1443113036547_0001
2015-09-24 12:45:07,604 INFO [main]  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2015-09-24 12:45:09,402 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2015-09-24 12:45:10,187 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://hadoop-coc-1:9000/input1/b.txt:0+21
2015-09-24 12:45:10,812 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task:attempt_1443113036547_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
2015-09-24 12:45:10,969 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task attempt_1443113036547_0001_m_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
2015-09-24 12:45:10,993 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_1443113036547_0001_m_000000_0' to hdfs://192.168.10.110:9000/output1-1442847968/_temporary/1/task_1443113036547_0001_m_000000
2015-09-24 12:45:11,135 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_1443113036547_0001_m_000000_0' done.
2015-09-24 12:45:11,135 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping MapTask metrics system...
2015-09-24 12:45:11,136 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics system stopped.
2015-09-24 12:45:11,136 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics system shutdown complete.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error. It is a bug in my code.

Comment: It would be good, if you can provide more information about the bug and fix. Otherwise this could not be considered as answer.